# How can you run an NPM script with blank in name?

Tags: npm

How can you run this script with `npm run` ?

Can you do something like `npm run "something cool"` ?

```
{
  "name": "nodejs_tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "something cool": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Did you try that? What happened?